# R: Replacing multiple matches with matches

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to shorten some regex matches in strings. Here is an example

```
vYears = c('Democrat 2000-2004',
                 'Democrat 2004-2008',
                 'Democrat 2008-2012',
                 'Republican 2000-2004',
                 'Republican 2004-2008',
                 'Republican 2008-2012',
                 'Tossup')
```

I can match the expression that I want, and get the matches, like so

```
grepYears = gregexpr('20[0-9]{2}', vYears)
regmatches(vYears, grepYears)
```

However, I am trying to shorten the strings to

```
vYearsShort = c('Democrat 00-04',
           'Democrat 04-08',
           'Democrat 08-12',
           'Republican 00-04',
           'Republican 04-08',
           'Republican 08-12',
           'Tossup')
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `gsub`.  Make use of backreferences to capture the desired part:

```
> vYears = c('Democrat 2000-2004',
+                  'Democrat 2004-2008',
+                  'Democrat 2008-2012',
+                  'Republican 2000-2004',
+                  'Republican 2004-2008',
+                  'Republican 2008-2012',
+                  'Tossup')
> vYearsShort = gsub("20([0-9]{2})", "\\1", vYears)
> vYearsShort
[1] "Democrat 00-04"   "Democrat 04-08"   "Democrat 08-12"   "Republican 00-04"
[5] "Republican 04-08" "Republican 08-12" "Tossup"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can match the following regex:

`^(\w+\s)20(\d{2}-)20(\d{2})$`

and replace with:

`\1\2\3` or `$1$2$3` or `\\1\\2\\3`

for earch string in your array.

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/hM4nX4)